# shopify storefront api how to list products in a single collection

Tags: shopify, graphql, shopify-app

I am using the following graphql to list all products in all collections, I am trying to modify this now to only list products in a single collection, I know the collection ID already but I cannot figure out where to put it in order to filter on the collection ID.

```
{
  shop {
    collections(first: 10) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          description
          products(first: 250) {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                description
                variants(first: 10) {
                  edges {
                    node {
                      id
                      sku
                      price
                      selectedOptions {
                        name
                        value
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        cursor
      }
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of grabbing all collections and then filtering, you can just grab a collection by its handle.

```
{
  shop {
    collectionByHandle(handle: "frontpage") {
      id
      description
      products(first: 250) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            description
            variants(first: 10) {
              edges {
                node {
                  id
                  sku
                  price
                  selectedOptions {
                    name
                    value
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
          cursor
        }
        pageInfo {
          hasNextPage
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Just replace `frontpage` with whatever your handle you like.

Answer (score 1):

```
Here is another answer with particular collection id wise


{
shop {
    .node(id: <YOUR COLLECTION ID>) {
        .onCollection {
            .products(first: 10) {
                pageInfo {
                    hasNextPage
                }
                edges {
                    node {
                        id
                        description
                        variants(first: 10) {
                            edges {
                                node {
                                    id
                                    sku
                                    price
                                    selectedOptions {
                                        name
                                        value
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```